# How to make an executable .py available everywhere on OS X?

Tags: python, path

I have this directory **/foo/bar/**. Inside, I have a python file named **myfile.py**. I made it executable by adding (at the top):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then, I made it executable by issuing

```
chmod +x myfile.py
```

I edited my path by issuing

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

I added **/foo/bar/** to it.

The problem is that although I can run myfile.py by typing **./myfile.py** while I am inside **/foo/bar/**, it doesn't work from any other location. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `/foo/bar` to your `$PATH` environment variable. Navigate to your home directory by typing `cd` at the prompt, then type `nano .profile`. Inside this file, add the following line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar
```

then save and quit. Exit Terminal.app (or whichever term program you're using) and restart it. `/foo/bar` should now be in your search path, to make sure type `echo $PATH` and see if it's at the end. You should now be able to run `myfile.py` from anywhere.

Comment: It is at the end of my $PATH (it already was but I tried adding what you proposed to .profile as well). When I type "myfile.py" anywhere, it tells me "command not found".

Comment: First, make sure everything is spelled correctly - `/usr/loacl/bin` has gotten me before :). I assume you're using `bash` as your shell, right? Type `source ~/.profile` (to make sure it's being read), then type `hash` to refresh the shell's memory of the search path.

Comment: When I type source ~/.profile, all I see is a blank line. So I guess it is not being read as when editing it, I see the export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar line in it. What should I do?

Comment: You won't see anything when typing `source ~/.profile`. What the `source` command coes is read the file and execute what's contained within it. After you run the `source` command and run `hash`, are you able to run `myfile.py`?

Comment: Yes! It works finally. Thank you! I'll accept your answer as the correct one even though the solution is in comments.

Comment: I'm glad everything finally worked out. I'm not sure what was wrong initially, as my original instructions should have worked, but at least you got to learn some more terminal commands :)

Answer (score 2):

At your terminal type:

```
which python
```

make sure that this path in the shebang at in the 1st line of your .py file. On my system it is

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

then 1st try:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/where/your/script/is
```

in any terminal

check that the PATH actually stuck by checking:

```
$PATH
```

should have path to your script in there now.

you should now be able to launch you script form anywhere.

the PATH will reset once you close terminal though so you should get pay do get it added permanently to your PATH.

good solution is to have the following bit of code in you .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

see writeup e.g. http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html  this will ensure that .bashrc is loaded every time the terminal is launched as well as when you launch a subshell.   Put the export

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/where/your/script/is
```

line somewhere in your .bashrc file.   quit and restart terminal.   That should sort everything out

Answer (score 0):

## Which python are you targeting?

#### Did you install it with brew? It uses a different path.

`which python3` or `which python`

Choose the one you want

Copy that output

Paste it at the top of your python file

add a `#!` in front of that path so it looks something like

#### `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`

Make sure to change the file permissions

#### `chmod +x filename`

Put that file in a folder that is in your path

#### Not sure if your folder is in your path?

`echo $path`

#### How to add that folder to your path?

Find your path first

`echo $HOME`

If you are using bash or zsh you might have something like this

In `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` at the bottom of your file

`export PYTHON_UTILS="$HOME/code/python/utils"`

`export PATH="$PYTHON_UTILS:$PATH"`

Consider removing the `.py` from your file bc it is not needed in this case

Close and open your terminal, which is sourcing your file by its path

And now you should be able to treat your python file similar to a bash command

You don't need to use `python3 filename.py` to run the file, you can just use `filename`

#### From anywhere on your filesystem!